# Copying cell data between Worksheets based on condition

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a Worksheet (main) with 2 columns that looks like the below:

Name    Nationality

John Smith  British

Chris Banks American

Jean Pierre French

My requirement is to transfer the cell data in Worksheet (main) to a secondary Worksheet based on the Nationality data. The secondary Worksheet for British should look like the below:

Name    Nationality

John Smith  British

Only the data associated with the British Nationality should filter through to this Worksheet as per above. I have looked at using paste links but this does not fulfill my requirement exactly. Would appreciate any assistance/advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: @Matt I was trying to use paste links/linked cells as I am not of a technical background. Will this definitely require coding or is there no nifty excel trick that can help me achieve my goal?

Comment: You could just use the autofilter function and manual copy paste.  http://www.wikihow.com/Use-AutoFilter-in-MS-Excel

Comment: @OO_Learner How many nationalities do you have in your sheet (approximately)?

Comment: @CaptainABC 12 nationalities

Comment: @OO_Learner Is this number fixed or will it eventually increase & change dynamically?

Comment: @CaptainABC this is likely to increase with time.

Comment: I am looking into it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a workbook and in "Sheet1" enter your data as you need:

[image: Sheet1]
<sub>(source: [gulfup.com](http://im59.gulfup.com/fULkNN.png))</sub>

Then add a command button (ActiveX) as above and add the code.

So the code that I have written for you will:

- Delete all previous sheets except "Sheet1".
- Add a "Temp" sheet.
- Copy the "Nationalities" column (Column B) from Sheet1 to TempSheet.
- Remove any duplicates to get the list of unique nationalities in the sheet.
- For each of the unique nationalities create a sheet named with the nationality.
- Filter by the names matching this nationality in "Sheet1" and copy results to the created sheet named with the respective nationality.
- Do this for all unique nationalities until the end.
- Auto-fit all column widths in the newly created sheets.
- Lastly delete the "Temp" sheet.

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Worksheet.Visible = True
Next
    
For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Worksheet.Name <> "Sheet1" Then Worksheet.Delete
Next

Worksheets.Add().Name = "TempSheet"

lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim copyRange  As Range
Set copyRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & lastrow)

copyRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("TempSheet").Range("A1")

On Error Resume Next
Lastrow2 = Worksheets("TempSheet").Cells(Worksheets("TempSheet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("TempSheet").Range("$A$1:$A$" & Lastrow2).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

Lastrow3 = Worksheets("TempSheet").Cells(Worksheets("TempSheet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Lastrow3
Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = Worksheets("TempSheet").Range("A" & i).Value

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    With .Range("A1:B" & lastrow)
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Worksheets("TempSheet").Range("A" & i).Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Set copyFrom = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    End With
End With

With Worksheets(Worksheets("TempSheet").Range("A" & i).Value)
    copyFrom.Copy .Rows(1)
End With

Worksheets(Worksheets("TempSheet").Range("A" & i).Value).Columns("A:Z").AutoFit

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
Next i

Worksheets("TempSheet").Delete

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I trust that this does what you need it to do.

Sample file: https://www.mediafire.com/?0zfooccuh86ikq8